# My website's https is crossed out

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https

I recently bought SSL certificate from godaddy and installed in my website. But my wordpress website is showing 'https' as crossed out. Can anyone check and tell me why this is happening. https://www.cinezone.in

[image]

I changed all the external links to 'https' from the source. But still it is showing cross mark. What is the problem?

Comment: Check it out at www.ssllabs.com/ssltest. Looks like you have not configured the webserver to provide the intermediate cert as well as your site cert so it can't build a chain back to a trusted cert.

Comment: Can you people tell me why you gave negative voting for this question? What more details do you want? Do you need my wordpress admin username, password, my bank account number??

Comment: It wasn't me but you often get that for asking non-programming questions on here. I argue that web development is starting to require more and more of infra knowledge but I'm in the minority :-)

Comment: How can you say that it is not related to programming.. May be some plugin in my wordpress site is not allowing the https in the url, someone may check and tell me that. Why do you jump into conclusions?

Comment: Because I can see the problem and it's not related to programming (as I already stated). It's related to how your SSL cert has been configured. However even without that 1) it was not me that downvoted (as I already stated) and 2) people are free to vote as they like - if they don't think your question belongs here, or has not given enough detail, or expects others to do all the basic investigation work that the original poster should do, then they are entirely entitled to downvote. I would agree with the downvote to be honest though am a little more forgiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the CA is not trusted, this could be an error from godaddy, but just to make sure go and issue a free certificate from https://www.startssl.com/ and check if the result is the same.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will check.

Comment: let me know what you get, so we can continue finding other possibilities

Comment: I applied for SSL in startssl website. Meanwhile I complained in Go daddy. They fixed it. I am not getting the cross out now. Thank you.